# Pros/Cons of Publishing iPhone Apps as Individual or Company (LLC, S-corp)?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to eventually publish one of the iPhone projects I've been working on and I was wondering if I should really establish an LLC before joining the Apple Dev program and submitting apps under the company name, rather than just using my name for both.  I'm looking for any legal or financial differences between the two options...as well as anecdotes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you produce an application as an LLC you as a person are not held accountable for any damages your application may cause. So if you somehow break a bunch of iPhones with your app and the court finds in favor of the victims the charges and fines are directed at the LLC and not you (and your personal bank accounts and assets)

At least that's my understanding. I'm not lawyer though so get this kind of thing double checked.

Comment: That's my understanding as well.  Does Apple take any of the responsibility given that they review the applications before posting them for sale?

Comment: Oh, and they take a cut of the proceeds. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many benefits to forming a company to insulate yourself from legal consequences.  There are also tax consequences and differences between a LLC or other corporate structure.  You should probably consult an attorney or at least your tax guy for advice.